# Problems with SQL cursor - keeps returning NULL

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cursor

I have a cursor that is to iterate over multiple rows from another table.

This is done by adding the cursor into the trigger, and to iterate through the rows that are inserted as a bulk from another table.

For example: A number of projects are added into the atsproject table, this then triggers the add trigger below to add into the vatmatrixtable.

The problem I'm having is that the cursor will through and add all the row values as null.

Is there a way to diagnose this further?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_VATMATRIX] ON [dbo].[atsproject]
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS

DECLARE @project AS VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @client AS VARCHAR(25) 
DECLARE @dim2 AS VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @period_from AS INT
DECLARE @period_to AS INT 
DECLARE @status AS CHAR(1)
DECLARE @user_id AS VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @unit_id AS VARCHAR(25)

--DECLARE @ROW_NUM VARCHAR (25)

DECLARE @sequence_no AS INT 

--DECLARE @TrigTempUpdate_Cursor CURSOR

--FIND MAXIMUM VALUE FOR SEQUENCE NUMBER
SET @sequence_no = (SELECT MAX(v) FROM (SELECT sequence_no FROM agldefmatdet WHERE matrix_id = 11) AS value(v));

DECLARE Tbl_Cursor CURSOR FOR  

SELECT project,
    client,
    dim2,
    period_from,
    period_to,
    status,
    user_id,
    unit_id
    FROM inserted

OPEN Tbl_Cursor;  

FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl_Cursor;  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  


   BEGIN  

   --SELECT TOP 1 * FROM inserted

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM deleted)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[agldefmatdet] 
        (att_val_from_1, 
            att_val_from_2,
            att_val_from_3,
            att_val_from_4,
            att_val_to_1,
            att_val_to_2,
            att_val_to_3,
            att_val_to_4, 
            att_value_1,
            att_value_2,
            att_value_3,
            att_value_4, 
            client, 
            dim_value, 
            last_update, 
            matrix_id, 
            period_from,
            period_to,
            sequence_no,
            status, 
            user_id)
    SELECT @project, 
            '', 
            '',
            '', 
            @project, 
            '', 
            '',
            '',
            @project, 
            '', 
            '',
            '',
            @client, 
            @dim2, 
            GETDATE(), 
            '11',
            '0',
            '0',
            @sequence_no + 1, 
            @status, 
            @user_id
RETURN;


  IF EXISTS (select * from inserted) AND EXISTS (select * from deleted)

  UPDATE agldefmatdet 
  SET dim_value = @dim2,
            last_update = GETDATE(),
            period_from = @period_from, 
            period_to = @period_to,
            status = @status,
            user_id = @user_id
            WHERE att_val_from_1 = @project AND matrix_id = '11' AND client = 'LU'


RETURN;
      FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl_Cursor;  
   END;  
CLOSE Tbl_Cursor;  
DEALLOCATE Tbl_Cursor;  
GO
```

Comment: and this doesnt throw an error? and why do you need a cursor anyway?

Comment: The reason the value is `NULL` is because you need to specified the list of variables on the `FETCH` statement.  There are many other errors too, such as the extraneous `RETURN` statements that will exit the trigger prematurely.  I suggest you ditch this version and rewrite using set-based methods instead of cursors.  This will improve performance and make the code much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

While not endorsing the method or debugging the rest of the code, your immediate issue is the fetch next statements, they should map the columns in the cursor declaration to variables you'll use within your loop;

```
FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl_Cursor
INTO @project,@client,@dim2,@period_from,@period_to,@status,@user_id,@unit_id;
```

EDIT: **As a set based solution**;

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_VATMATRIX] ON [dbo].[atsproject]
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS

DECLARE @sequence_no AS INT 

--DECLARE @TrigTempUpdate_Cursor CURSOR

--FIND MAXIMUM VALUE FOR A MATRIX 11 SEQUENCE NUMBER
/* replaced with select below
SET @sequence_no = (SELECT MAX(v) FROM (SELECT sequence_no FROM agldefmatdet WHERE matrix_id = 11) AS value(v));
*/

SELECT @sequence_no = max(sequence_no) FROM agldefmatdet WHERE matrix_id = 11; /* NB, hard coding IDs isn't a good idea */


    INSERT INTO [dbo].[agldefmatdet] 
        (att_val_from_1, 
            att_val_from_2,
            att_val_from_3,
            att_val_from_4,
            att_val_to_1,
            att_val_to_2,
            att_val_to_3,
            att_val_to_4, 
            att_value_1,
            att_value_2,
            att_value_3,
            att_value_4, 
            client, 
            dim_value, 
            last_update, 
            matrix_id, 
            period_from,
            period_to,
            sequence_no,
            status, 
            user_id)
    SELECT project, 
            '', 
            '',
            '', 
            project, 
            '', 
            '',
            '',
            project, 
            '', 
            '',
            '',
            client, 
            dim2, 
            GETDATE(), 
            '11',
            '0',
            '0',
            @sequence_no + row_number() over (order by project), /* order doesn't appear important so column listed here shouldn't matter */
            status, 
            user_id
    from inserted

  UPDATE a 
  SET dim_value = i.dim2,
            last_update = GETDATE(),
            period_from = i.period_from, 
            period_to = i.period_to,
            status = i.status,
            user_id = i.user_id

    from agldefmatdet a
    inner join inserted i   /* replaces previous where statement */
        on i.project = a.att_val_from_1
        and '11' = a.matrix_id
        and 'LU' = a.client

RETURN;
GO
```

Comment: Hi Edward,Thanks - this has solved the NULL error, however the cursor inserts the last row of the multiple rows inserted into the atsproject table. I've has this error before but its difficult to work out!

Comment: Hi @user3565164, I've added an example of this trigger as a set based statement. Untested it so there may be errors or not work exactly as you intend but I hope it can add a base for you to work from in a better technique. NB, you have to update BOTH fetch next statements to include the assignment ;-)

Comment: And remove the return statements inside the loop, just have one at the end of the trigger

Comment: Brilliant! You're welcome. But do try to avoid cursors for row by row processing of data, it's generally the case that it will perform poorly when scaling and set-based statements will give far better results.